# Changing the color of a Rebol button

Tags: button, view, rebol

I want to ask multiple choice questions in Rebol. Possible answers will be on buttons. I want to turn a button red when it is clicked *and* it is the wrong answer. When the correct button is pressed, I want to proceed to the next question.

I can change the color of a box (mybox/color: red show mybox). I can set up a toggle with two colors (but I can't change it based on the result of an arbitrary test (is the answer correct?).

It seems like there is probably a simple way to change the color of a button, without having to create my own button-like face objects. Isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? The button starts RED. Left click turns it BLUE, right click turns it GREEN:

```
unview/all
view layout [
   my-btn: button 200x50 "left click or right click to change color" red effect []
       [my-btn/color: blue  show my-btn]  ;; effect of left click
       [my-btn/color: green show my-btn]  ;; effect of right click
  ]
```

You can define that in a STYLE so any other button can inherit the behavior.